# python: timing of __new__ in metaclass

Tags: python, namespaces, metaclass

The following code doesn't compile; it says

> NameError: name 'fields' is not
>   defined

in the last line. Is it because `__new__` isn't called until after the `fields` assignment is reached? What should I do?

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attr):
        attr['fields'] = {}
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attr)

class A(metaclass = Meta):
    def __init__(self, name):
        pass

class B(A):
    fields['key'] = 'value'
```

**EDIT:**

I found that it's not a problem with timing; it's a problem with name hiding. Works fine if I write `A.fields` instead.

I'd like to know why I can't use `fields` or `super().fields`.

Comment: what do you want to do with `fields`? there is almost surely a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm building a class hierarchy that will be stored in a database. `fields` contains the dictionary of columns that I want to store, and their database types (like INTEGER, VARCHAR, etc.). I wanted to add more columns to the subclass, so was trying to update the `fields` attribute.

Comment: see my answer. I think I've implemented what you want but you might need to tweak it a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fields['key'] = 'value'` runs before the metaclass machinery kicks in.

```
class foo(object):
    var1 = 'bar'

    def foobar(self):
        pass
```

when python hits the `class` statement, it enters a new local namespace.

1. it evaluates the `var1 = 'bar'` statement. this is equivalent to `locals()['var1'] = 'bar'`
2. it then evaluates the `def foobar` statement. this is equivalent to `locals()['var'] = the result of compiling the function`
3. It **then**  passes `locals()`, along with the classname, the inherited classes and the metaclass to the metaclasses `__new__` method. In the example case, the metaclass is simply `type`.
4. It then exits the new local namespace and sticks the class object returned from `__new__` in the outer namespace with the name `foo`.

Your code works when you use `A.fields` because the class `A` has already been created and the above process has hence been executed with your `Meta` installing `fields` in `A`.

You can't use `super().fields` because the classname `B` is not defined to pass to super at the time that super would run. that is that you would need it to be `super(B).fields` but `B` is defined **after**  class creation.

### Update

Here's some code that will do what you want based on your reply to my comment on the question.

```
def MakeFields(**fields):
    return fields

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attr):
        for base in bases:
            if hasattr(base, 'fields'):
                inherited = getattr(base, 'fields')
                try:
                    attr['fields'].update(inherited)
                except KeyError:
                    attr['fields'] = inherited
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attr)

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    fields = MakeFields(id='int',name='varchar') 

class B(A):
    fields = MakeFields(count='int')

class C(B):
    pass

class Test(object):
    fields = "asd"

class D(C, Test):
    pass

print C.fields
print D.fields
```

Comment: But if that's the case, why does `A.fields['key'] = 'value'` work fine?

Comment: Ahh, so class name isn't usable at the "class level", only inside the individual class methods.. That makes sense, since the code inside the functions isn't evaluated until much later, when the class already exists.